# Pass profile property in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I set several profiles that contain base url

So I could pass -P test or dev in the command in order to change environments

So when I do via command line as mvn clean test .... -P test
that works

However, I cannot find on how to enable such in IntelliJ Idea under job configuration
VM options no good

Comment: You can always add VM options for running Maven.  Look under Settings->Build Tools->Maven->Runner.

Answer (score 2):

In IntelliJ under `Run/Debug Configuration`, click the green `+` in the top left and click Maven.

Under Command line enter `mvn clean test`, under Profiles enter your profile name (no need to add -P here, just the name is enough)

Answer (score 2):

Run can use the Maven tool view within IntelliJ to run Maven goals from within IntelliJ. This view is available via `View > Tool Windows > Maven`.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

You can run any goal by ...

- Double clicking it
- Right mouse click and choose run from the context menu
- Clicking on the run icon (the green right arrow) in the menu bar

When running any of these goals you can specify a profile by clicking on this icon:

[image]

Then you can set the profile name in the `Command line` in `Execute Maven Goal` dialog:

[image]

Note: you might also choose to make your `dev` profile the default profile so that it is engaged without having to specify it.

Comment: Thank you, that works only if I want to run whole thing, , however, I use Cucumber and within Run/Debug configuration it appears as Cucumber java, not as Maven, there is no Command line section imgur.com/VbTwNqb

Answer (score 1):

Run/Debug Configurations... -> Maven -> "Profiles (separated with space)" textbox